# keeping a constant number for a column in excel and change row number in different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two-sheet in an excel file.

Metric and Overview.    I refer to Metric data in overview sheet-like  `=Metric!BB12.`

For me, `BB` will change based on each file report I create. So when the value is BB next month, I want to move it to BC,  BD, BE BF etc., the 12 and other matters in other places are constant.

My ask is ...  Is it possible to make `BB` a variable, and when I move the

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX` in combination of `MATCH`.

Assumptions of data:

Sheet `Metric` keeps header values in row 1
Headers are text

Example with assumptions:
`=INDEX('Metric'!$12:$12,,MATCH("ColumnHeaderName",'Metric'!$1:$1,0))`

Change "ColumnHeaderName" into the value you want to match against.

Edit: added `$` to lock rows if you may want to copy down the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer row number as absolute reference. Use `$` dollar sign in-front of row number. Try-

```
=Metric!BB$12
```